# How do you get a parent class to return type T?

Tags: java

These are some of the classes that I'm using

```java
public abstract class DCDataManager<T extends DCData> {
    public T getData(UUID id){
        return cache.get(id);
    }
...
```

```java
public class ApfelPlayerDataManager extends DCPlayerDataManager<ApfelPlayerData>{
    public ApfelPlayerDataManager(DrycellPlugin plugin) {
        super(plugin);
        this.type = ApfelPlayerData.class;
        this.loadCurrentPlayers();
    }
....
```

Based on the above classes, why do I need to cast `apfelPlayerDataManager.getData(p.getUniqueId())` to `ApfelPlayerData`? Shouldn't it always return an `ApfelPlayerData` instance?

```java
ApfelPlayerDataManager apfelPlayerDataManager = new ApfelPlayerDataManager(this);
ApfelPlayerData data = apfelPlayerDataManager.getData(p.getUniqueId());
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `apfelPlayerDataManager`. I suspect it is a raw type (ie untyped)

Comment: You mean the "public class ApfelPlayerDataManager extends DCPlayerDataManager<ApfelPlayerData>{"? It's there though. Or you mean the instantiation of it?

Comment: The instance. Show the declaration of the variable `apfelPlayerDataManager`

Comment: Okay, added the stuff to the main thread

Comment: This looks suspicious: `this.type = ApfelPlayerData.class;` you haven’t shown the `type` field nor where it’s used. Depending on where it’s defined and how it’s used, that could be your problem. Possibly relevant: fields cannot be overridden.

Comment: It's hard to show everything because it extends quite far into the rest of the code, but I'm confident that it's not particularly related because this problem occurred before that change was done.

Perhaps an example could help a bit more. Do you know of an example where something like this was done successfully?

Comment: Your superclass is named `DCDataManager`, but your subclass extends `DCPlayerDataManager`. Are these two names meant to be the same? If so, please  correct the mistake. If not, please explain what is going on.

Comment: It's not a mistake, DCPlayerDataManager is meant to be a child class of DCDataManager. The player data manager is meant to inherit attributes and methods from the abstract DCDataManager class.

Comment: to get any help, you need to show *all* the relevant classes. You can omit implementation details, but the class and method signatures are critical - without *all* of them, we can’t help you.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, found the problem. Thanks Bohemian, the last reply led me to look in the right direction.

Basically I had 3 classes:

```java
public class DCDataManager<T extends DCData>

public class DCPlayerDataManager<T> extends DCDataManager

public class ApfelPlayerDataManager extends DCPlayerDataManager<ApfelPlayerData>
```

The problem stemmed from the second class' definition. This worked:

```java
public class DCDataManager<T extends DCData>

public class DCPlayerDataManager<T extends DCData> extends DCDataManager<T>

public class ApfelPlayerDataManager extends DCPlayerDataManager<ApfelPlayerData>
```